# Can you prove that function is positive for certain values using limit of function?

Tags: limits, infinity

Here's example:

Prove that $x-\frac{1}{x^2} \geq 0$ for every $x \ge 1$

I know that this can be done using elementary algebra, but in other cases it's not that simple. Can I prove this inequation positive for every $x \ge 1$ if I show that it's positive for the smallest value, that's 1 in this case and then that limit of the function
$f(x) = x-\frac{1}{x^2}$ as x approaches infinitiy is infinity?

Comment: Er... do you mean $\geq 0$? Because when $x = 1$...

Comment: Yes it should be $\geq 0$. My bad

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.  There are functions that start and end positive but are negative somewhere in the middle.  On the other hand, if you could show that your function is increasing...

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can't. Consider the function $y=x(x-1)(x-2)$ as a counterexample.

However, try looking at the derivative of the function as this will tell you how the function changes over time and hence if it will stay non-negative.

P.S. You may want to check your inequalities as currently your statement isn't true for $x=1$

Comment: I don't understand why your function is counterexample, for every $x>2$ it's bigger than 0.

Comment: But not for x between 1 and 2 or less than 0.

Comment: the function was chosen to closely match your example. It is 0 when $x=1$ and tends to infinity as x tends to infinity but it is not greater than or equal to zero for all $x\ge1$ as it is negative for $1<x<2$